# How do we know not all photons are absorbed? Only those of specific energies?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, photons, electrons, atomic-physics

When a photon hits an electron in an atom, its energy has to be equal to the difference in energy between the current shell and a shell with a higher energy level, otherwise it is not absorbed at all.

How do we know not all photons are absorbed? Wouldn't at least some energy of the photon be absorbed since it is an oscillation in the EM field?

Comment: There is a small chance that any photon energy would be absorbed.  But except for energies near a transition energy, the chance of absorption is very very very small.

Comment: @garyp but the electron would not move energy level? So it would re-emit this photon after absorption?

Comment: @garyp So what would happen after? Would the electron stay within the same shell because not enough energy was provided? Would another photon be re-emmited?

Comment: Most of the "strength" of the energy level is close to the central energy.  But there is "strength" at energies as far away as you want. The photon *can* be absorbed if its energy doesn't match a transition energy, but the photon is much much much more likely to pass on by.   It's a bit like finding an electron one meter from the atom.   There is a probability that it will be found there, but the probability is very very very very small

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do we know not all photons are absorbed?

You can shine monochromatic light on a sample of a material and see whether it is absorbed or not.

For example if you shine different wavelengths of light through a chamber containing a pure gas, and you'll see that only wavelengths that match transitions of that gas molecule are absorbed. Wavelengths that are either too long or too short are not absorbed.

> Wouldn't at least some energy of the photon be absorbed since it is an oscillation in the EM field?

It's not possible to absorb "some" of the energy of a photon. The whole concept of a photon is that it is the *quantum* of energy in the EM field. That means that when something exchanges energy with the EM field, it does so in units of whole photon energies, not fractions of the photon energy.

Comment: So it's because of the particle-like model of the photon?

Comment: @XXb8, yes, when we say a photon is "particle-like" it's shorthand for saying that energy can only be exchanged with the EM field in specific amounts, which we call the photon energy.

Comment: What if a photon has more energy than the 1st IE but less than the 2nd IE?

Comment: @XXb8, changed my example to better address your question.

Comment: Now it seems much clearer! But still, what would happen if a photon has more energy than the 1st IE but less than the 2nd IE?

Comment: @XXb8, what does "IE" mean?

Comment: ionisation energy. Sorry, I didn't think this through, and this is not the correct term to use. I meant if a photon had enough energy to excite the electron to one energy level higher and a little energy leftover?

Comment: @XXb8, then it won't be absorbed (except with very very low probability). This is shown by the absorption spectra in the answer just posted by anna v.

Comment: So what would happen if it were? Would the electron stay within the same shell because not enough energy was provided? Would another photon be re-emmited?

Comment: Or the energy would go somewhere else. In a solid, a phonon could be produced, for example.

Comment: Why is the probability of a photon with too little energy to move energy level being absorbed 'low'?

Comment: @XXb8, it would depend on the exact molecule and transition you're testing, and the exact energy of the photon. You should research *spectroscopy* to see the work of 100's of physicists who have studied these kind of questions in the 19th and 20th C, which was an important motivator for the development of quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the spectrum of light coming from the sun.

[image: sunspectr]

> [Solar spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_spectroscopy) with Fraunhofer lines as it appears visually.

The  spectrum seen has all the wavelengths ( frequency = c/wavelength), and the dark lines are the absorption lines. Absorption and emission lines are one of the reasons quantum mechanics had to be invented.

> Wouldn't at least some energy of the photon be absorbed since it is an oscillation in the EM field

The photon is a point  [elementary particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle) of energy=to $hν$, it is not a classcical electromagnetic oscillation. It is described by a wavefunction which is not measurable. The complex conjugate square of the wavenctions give the probability of finding the photon  at (x, y,z,t)  with energy E , and the dark lines show an overwhelming  probability for the specific frequency/energy photon to be absorbed.

Light is composed by zillions of photons superimposed,  but a photon is not light. (a buildingis made of bricks, but a brick is not a building is a classical analogue)

Answer (score 0):

We can shoot photons of different energies at atoms and see what goes thru and what is absorbed.  only the specific energy photons will be absorbed. And no part of the energy will not. This is one of the results from quantum mechanics. The first excitation energy of hydrogen is 10.2 ev.  If you shoot photons of energy 12 ev, part of it will not excite the H atom. You need a photon of 10.2 ev to excite the H atom.

Comment: What if a photon has more energy than the 1st IE but less than the 2nd IE?

Comment: what is IE?  sorry but i don't know.